# How to add a rank in a array on Java using switch

Tags: java, arrays, string, switch-statement

Hi guys I wait you're nice
I have a question about arrays in Java, I wanna add a sentence with if and else where the array have a rank for example:

```
String [] menu = {"Arroz","Papas","Pollo","Sopa","carne","Bandeja Paisa"};
     System.out.println("Bienvenido al restaurante x ¿Desea probar el menu del dia o alguna comida especifica?");
     String usuario = input.nextLine();
     if ((usuario.equals("Menu")||(usuario.equals("Menu del dia"))))
     {for(int i = 0; i < menu.length; i++){System.out.println("Los platos para el dia de hoy son: "+ menu[i]);}
         System.out.println("¿Cual deseas comer?");String opcion = input.nextLine();
```

instead of use a cicle I want print the arrays with a certain rank in a only message.

also I wanna do a switch with possibles input of strings because I think that is the better way to use in this situation instead of a "if" but this don't work,for example

```
{System.out.println("Los platos para el dia de hoy son: " + Arrays.toString(menu));}
        System.out.println("¿Cual deseas comer?");String opcion = input.nextLine();

        switch(){
        case 1: opcion.equals("Pollo");
                System.out.println("El plato " + opcion + " estara listo dentro de 60 segundos.");
                 break;
```

Sorry if you don't understand, English isn't my native language and I deny use translator or similar.
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write out the menus with the Java-8 forEach method:

```
System.out.println("Los platos para el dia de hoy son:");
java.util.Arrays.asList(menu).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Your switch statement could read like this (you will need at least Java 1.7):

```
switch(opcion) {
case "Pollo":
    System.out.println("El plato " + opcion + " estara listo dentro de 60 segundos.");
    break;
```

Comment: Thanks very much for reply!

Answer (score 0):

Make these changes:

- Print the question heading *before* the loop
- Print the index of each plate

Like this:

```
if ((usuario.equals("Menu")||(usuario.equals("Menu del dia")))) {
    System.out.println("Los platos para el dia de hoy son:);
    for (int i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(i + ": " + menu[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("¿Cual deseas comer?");
    int opcion = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
    String plato = menu[opcion];
}
```

You should consider using a `Map<String, Integer>` to hold the plate prices. If you do that, with the above code, you don't need a `switch`.

Comment: and if i wanna print a rank of element of the arrays for example: System.out.println(Menu[0-2]) what i need do?

Comment: @luis try something. If you have a problem, ask a new question about that problem. This isn't a discussion forum